# Alarmmanager - 2nd alarm not firing

Tags: android, android-intent, alarmmanager

I have a GCM intent service that I am using to set an alarm and another to set a second alarm, for testing purposes, I have the alarm receivers for both methods to display a toast.

The first toast is display but the second never appears. Individually they both work on their own. Can someone spot what I am doing wrong ?

Thanks

```
    private void gcmalarmset(Calendar targetCal, String hour, String minute) {

          Log.i(TAG,"gcmalarmset method started");

          //set alarm
          AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
          Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), test1.class);
          PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), 2, intent, 0);
          alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);




        }     

 private void alarmunset(Calendar targetCal, String hour, String minute) {

          Log.i(TAG,"gcmalarmunset method started");

          //set alarm
          AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
          Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), test2.class);
          PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), 1, intent, 0);
          alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

        }
```

Comment: witch version of sdk you use?

Comment: Platform 4.3 API level 18

Comment: can u place your full code here? there isn't any bug in your code